# Slitherlink: The Couple of Question Marks

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This is my first slitherlink puzzle. I made it myself. Feedback is appreciated! (I hope this one has a unique solution, unlike my other past puzzles, *wink*).

Rules of Slitherlink (taken from [Nikoli)](http://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/slitherlink.html):

> 1. Connect adjacent dots with vertical or horizontal lines to make a single loop.
> 2. The numbers indicate how many lines surround it, while empty cells may be surrounded by any number of lines.
> 3. The loop never crosses itself and never branches off.
> 4. **Extra rule**: The question marks indicate any number more than 0.

Here is the puzzle.

[image]

And [here](https://puzz.link/p?slither/10/10/3258522bbg6b68bgbi8a85.i860.dg2a6agb5d0a0bhb26dg6a) is a handy puzz.link, which is a playable version of the puzzle online.

Comment: Why the question marks?

Comment: Because I need to show that the snake passes by those squares

Comment: Ah, I see, so ? means >0. But do you need those? It looks like from the nearby 3 and 0 that that will have to be true.

Comment: I needed them for a good title, as in a ? couple kissing each other

Comment: Oh, okay, fair enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution:

> [image: slitherlink solution]
>  It is a pretty easy Slitherlink, many basic techniques can are applied. (yes, it has a unique solution.)

Explanation:

> Starting with the most basic one, mark the lines around 0's as X's, and if a point has only one direction to go (e.g. the 2 touching corners in 2 adjacent 0's), mark that corresponding part as X. After that, draw the lines in the numbers that have enough X's surrounding it.
>  [image: slitherlink progress 1]

> Notice a 2 in the corner. There are 2 possible ways to draw the lines:
>  [image: solving method]
>  We can deduce that 2 lines can be drawn that must be going away from 2 at the border (highlighted in red). We can draw more lines using Slitherlink logic:
>  [image: slitherlink progress 2]

> A little bit more logic:
>  [image: slitherlink progress 3]

> A bit of a tricky part. Notice the point marked in bold. If the line moves to east (orange), it would create another line surrounding it, which is a contradiction.
>  If the line moves to south (blue), the resulting line becomes a dead-end, since it cannot access the other loop segments to the right.
>  [image]
>  Concluding that the line moves west and using some more basic logic, the Slitherlink is complete.
>  [image: completed]

Comment: Congrats! You answered this in less than an hour after the puzzle was posted! Please add an explanation of how you got the solution, then the checkmark is all yours! ;)

Comment: And the check is yours!